# Unable to use any packages that i included while building for an ubuntu derived VM on a hypervisor

Tags: boot, kernel, virtualization

I want certain libraries on my Apertis VM on a QNX Hypervisor. The apertis image is built using YAML files, and it includes the libraries in the yaml file. When i build this image, it generates- dtb file, Initrd, the image, and a rootfs.tar.gz. When i include the first three in the partition, i get this:

Gave up waiting for root file system device.  Common problems:

- Boot args (cat /proc/cmdline)

  - Check rootdelay= (did the system wait long enough?)
- Missing modules (cat /proc/modules; ls /dev)
  ALERT!  /dev/vda does not exist.  Dropping to a shell!

[image of the above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AmM8G.png)

and while i see the libraries and binaries i require in the rootfs.tar.gz, i don't see them on the VM. Does the image already contain the rootfs or is it to be included in the partition with the image? Or am i missing something else here. Thank you.